# How to compare Edit Text to Variable That was converted to String in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[I'm a beginner to Android Studio and I am building this simple game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naodj.png)

My problem is that I tried to get the Value of the Edit Text and then converted it to string.
And I also converted my int variable to string in order to compare

see code below

```
fun entEvent(view: View){
    val sum = (firstnum + secondnum).toString()
    val text = editText2.text.toString()
    if (sum == text){
        val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        //Title for alert dialog
        alert.setTitle("Mental Math")

        //set message for alert dialog
        alert.setMessage(R.string.diaMessage)

        //performing positive action
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok"){
                dialogInterface, which ->
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Congrats, You are A math genius", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        val alertDialog: AlertDialog = alert.create()
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false)
        alertDialog.show()
    }
    if (sum!=text){

        val alert = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        //Title for alert dialog
        alert.setTitle("Mental Math")

        //set message for alert dialog
        alert.setMessage(R.string.diaMessage2)

        //performing positive action
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok"){
                dialogInterface, which ->
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Sorry, Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        val alertDialog: AlertDialog = alert.create()
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false)
        alertDialog.show()
    }

}
```

The problem is that if I check if the sum and text is equals it is always false. And I dont know what do anymore.

Comment: You should look up instructions/tutorials about using the debugger. You can put a breakpoint in your code at the `if` statement line and check if the two variables `sum` and `text` are what you expect them to be. That will help narrow down the problem. The code you've shown doesn't have any bugs that I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably because of whitespace.

Use the trim() command to get rid of whitespace

so

instead of (sum == text) use (sum == text.trim()).

ALso make sure that `firstnum + secondnum` both these nos have been converted to an Integer before calculation.

Ps: As @Tenfour04 said using the debugger would help you narrow it down
[Using Debugger in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019006/how-to-debug-an-android-app-using-android-studio)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you .:).  Welcome to stackOverflow .:)